# How does a miner know when to start mining. Given the miners are geographically dispersed, how all of them start mining together?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, bitcoin

When the transactions are sent from A to B, it can reach a miner (M1) first and other miner (m2) later then does (M1) starts mining instantly? And how many transactions are required for a miner to start mining?

Answer (score 0):

miners mine blocks, not individual transactions. they start work on already built blocks. these blocks can include any transactions, as long they are valid and the resulting block is valid, so yes miners M1 and M2 can work on the same block or entirely different blocks. these blocks can be empty, full or anything in between (in fact miners will start working on empty blocks until a block is built) in the end, the first solution published is (probably) going to "win" and enter the chain.

now there are uncle blocks and reorgs but these are other topics.